# Users in subsite are unable to access despite having "Contribute" Access

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

We have an Audit site and within that we have a Findings subsite.  There is a group with contributor access to this subsite called Findings Contributors, and they do NOT have access to the main site.

For some strange reason, they're unable to access the subsite.  Does anyone know why this group might not be able to access the subsite?

> Access Denied. Exception: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListsWithCallback(String
>   bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32
>   dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32
>   dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData,
>   Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean
>   bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32&
>   plRecycleBinCount) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String
>   bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32
>   dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32
>   dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData,
>   Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean
>   bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32&
>   plRecycleBinCount).   f7f92c9d-b400-6057-49ef-a8b3f8d19374

Comment: On the subsite did you break permission inheritance?

Comment: is this a migrated site? if so check if the user names are converted to Claims. User names should start like "i:0#.w|domain\user" instead of "domain\user"

Comment: Yes, the subsite has unique permissions and we recently upgraded our environment from 2010 to 2013.  However, I'm unable to confirm if these permissions worked correctly in 2010.

Comment: Can you try with this tool what is happening in the ULS log? sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com (look for the keyword access denied)

Comment: Do you know of a way I can narrow it down more?

Comment: I've attached what I believe is the error you're looking for.

Comment: Does users from that group has access to master pages  folder and site pages folder .if not add permissions to those folders and check again

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do I check this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure they still have "Limited Access" permission in the root site. This should be assigned automatically by SharePoint but something to check.

[what is limited access?](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/what-are-sharepoint-limited-access)

In SP2013 you won't see Limited Access on the permission pages. The Sharegate article above says you will see this message but I have not been able to get that to work:

> "There are limited access users on this site. Users may have limited access if an item or document under the site has been shared with them”.

Instead, you can use Powershell to verify that Limited Access is being granted as expected.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb <web url>
$web.RoleAssignments | ft Member,RoleDefinitionBindings
```

If you don't see the permissions you expect, I would try removing the permissions and reassign them in the subsite. This should make SharePoint grant limited access at the root. I've tested this in my environment. I have a list with broken inheritance. When I assign a user permissions to this list, that user is granted Limited Access at the root.

Comment: How can I check this?  I'm at the site collection level, but I don't see "Limited Access" listed under the different permission groups?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: I'm not seeing this message.  On the sub-sites permissions page, all I see is `This web site has unique permissions.` I'm worried that SharePoint is failing to automatically give the necessary Limited Access permissions.

Comment: The message would appear at the root.

Comment: It says, `Some content on this site has different permissions from what you see here. Show these items.`  Another question Lance...if I check this user's permissions at the root level, should it say "Limited Access"?  Because it's telling me they have NO Access at the root level.

Comment: They need Limited Access at the root. If they don't, I would try removing access in the subsite and granting again.

Comment: I did and that didn't help.  It seems that Limited Access isn't being given?

Comment: I can't get the Limited Access users to show either. Sorry for the unreliable info in the sharegate article. I usually trust them but maybe there is something I am doing wrong. I've updated my answer with some useful powershell you can use.

Answer (score 1):

This [site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074.aspx) shows the permissions that should be checked in the Contribute permission level.

Go to permission levels on your Sharepoint account, click on Contribute and make sure that those permissions under Contribute permission level is checked.